# How to get TODO sequence without exporting as a section?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I maintain an `org` file to organize my literature survey. The headline structure reflects the hierarchy of topics in my research area. Within each topic, there is a list of research articles. A `TODO` sequence helps me recall how deeply I have studied each article.

The problem is that, to use the `TODO` sequence, I need to have a headline for each article. During the export to `latex`, this results in a section created for each article, whereas I want to have a numbered list of articles within each topic. Setting `org-export-headline-levels` does not solve the problem, since topics can be nested a various levels.

Thus, it seems that I am looking to somehow associate `TODO` sequence with items rather than headlines. Is this possible? If not, is there an idiomatic solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using inline tasks.  The basic approach is described in this [entry in the Org FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#list-item-as-todo).  Here is an example:

```
#+OPTIONS: inline:nil num:nil toc:nil p:nil
#+SEQ_TODO: TO-READ STARTED | FINISHED 
#+SEQ_TODO: | ABANDONED
* List of papers
** First topic
1. First paper: a comment I want to be exported
*************** TO-READ 
A private comment, which won't be exported
*************** END

2. Second paper
*************** STARTED 
*************** END

3. Third paper
*************** FINISHED 
CLOSED: [2017-07-28 Fri 17:18]
*************** END

** Second topic
1. Second topic paper
*************** ABANDONED 
CLOSED: [2017-07-28 Fri 17:17]
*************** END

2. Another second topic paper
```

This exports via LaTeX to PDF (`C-c C-e l o`) as

[image: Screenshot of LaTeX export output]

To set this up, you need the following in your config file:

```
(require 'org-inlinetask)
(setq org-inlinetask-default-state "TO-READ")
```

Then, you can add an inline task with `C-c C-x t`, which will start in the `TO-READ` state.

If you ever **do** want all the metadata to be exported, you can just you edit the OPTIONS to `inline:t p:t`, which gives

[image: Result of exporting metadata too]

Comment: Nice! I am wondering whether another approach exists. For example, what about using regular headlines, but somehow indicating that all headlines in a given sub-tree should be exported as items (just like they would be exported if the level exceeded  `org-export-headline-levels`). Is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible, but I can't see an easy way to do it.  Although you can set, for example, `:EXPORT_OPTIONS: H:1` in a properties drawer for a given sub-tree, this only has an effect when you export *only* that sub-tree. It does not override the global `org-export-headline-levels` setting for that sub-tree when you are exporting the entire buffer.  I think you would have to modify the function `org-export-low-level-p` in `ox.el` if you want to do that.

Comment: Can `org-inlinetask-default-state` be set in the buffer, i.e. using the same mechanism as `#+SEQ_TODO`?